# How to write java logic to sql query

Tags: sql, select, aggregate-functions

I have a database query `select * from student;`

student table having below data.

```
language     countries      know    dontknow    members
--------      -------        ----    -------    --------
english          USA        50000   20000       500000
french         FRANCE       80000   30000       800000
jerman        German        30000   40000       900000
italian        Italy        20000   50000       700000
english          USA        50000   20000       500000
french         FRANCE       80000   30000       800000
jerman        German        30000   40000       900000
italian        Italy        20000   50000       700000
```

output would be like this:

```
country     know(sum)       dontknow(sum)   members(sum)
-------     --------        -------------   ------------
UsA         100000          40000       1000000
FRANCE      160000          60000       1600000
German      60000           80000       1800000
Italy       40000           100000      1400000
```

Comment: So, you need an SQL query to obtain aggregated data from your `student` table? What SQL flavor? (Oracle, MySQL, T-SQL etc.)?

Comment: i need jdbc code for the above mentioned output format

Comment: Hey Alex thanks for above answer. I have one more query please do need full. i need to merge languages of two and all countries with summation of remaining columns. Thanks! advance

Comment: please provide the query for above question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by the countries and sum the relevant columns:

```
SELECT   countries AS country, SUM(know), SUM(dontknow) SUM(members)
FROM     student
GROUP BY countries
```

Comment: Hey @Mureinik thanks for above answer. I have one more query please do need full. i need to merge languages of two and all countries with summation of remaining columns. Thanks! advance